# Insert from JSON TABLE, how to add subquery to fill one column with value outside JSON

Tags: sql, json, oracle, plsql

I got table

```
Name           Null?    Type         
-------------- -------- ------------ 
PONO           NOT NULL NUMBER(5)    
REQUESTOR               VARCHAR2(50) 
COSTCENTER              VARCHAR2(5)  
ADDRESSSTREET           VARCHAR2(50) 
ADDRESSCITY             VARCHAR2(50) 
ADDRESSSTATE            VARCHAR2(2)  
ADDRESSZIP              VARCHAR2(10) 
ADDRESSCOUNTRY          VARCHAR2(50) 
AD_INFO                 VARCHAR2(50)
```

And such insert

```
INSERT INTO purchaseorder
      SELECT * FROM json_table(L_PO  FORMAT JSON, '$'
         COLUMNS (
           PONo            Number    PATH '$.PONumber',
           Requestor       VARCHAR2  PATH '$.Requestor',
           CostCenter      VARCHAR2  PATH '$.CostCenter',
           AddressStreet   VARCHAR2  PATH '$.Address.street',
           AddressCity     VARCHAR2  PATH '$.Address.city',
           AddressState    VARCHAR2  PATH '$.Address.state',
           AddressZip      VARCHAR2  PATH '$.Address.zipCode',
           AddressCountry  VARCHAR2  PATH '$.Address.country'));
```

I want to add AD_INFO information from `select source from source_table where x=159`

Is it possibile to do this in one operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your table source_table contains the L_PO(json file) so you can use:

```
INSERT INTO purchaseorder
      SELECT sc.AD_INFO,jtbl.* FROM source_table sc,json_table(L_PO  FORMAT JSON, '$'
         COLUMNS (
           PONo            Number    PATH '$.PONumber',
           Requestor       VARCHAR2  PATH '$.Requestor',
           CostCenter      VARCHAR2  PATH '$.CostCenter',
           AddressStreet   VARCHAR2  PATH '$.Address.street',
           AddressCity     VARCHAR2  PATH '$.Address.city',
           AddressState    VARCHAR2  PATH '$.Address.state',
           AddressZip      VARCHAR2  PATH '$.Address.zipCode',
           AddressCountry  VARCHAR2  PATH '$.Address.country')) jtbl;
```